# Tikz Picture Arc Problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to recreate the attached image and I can't draw the red arc arrow on my circle.  I have tried arc, clip,etc and can't manage to figure it out.  [image]

Here is what I have come up with so far.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2.5,7)}]
\draw[Triangle-Triangle] (-2,0)--(2,0);
\draw[Triangle-Triangle] (0,-2)--(0,2);
\draw[thick,blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\node[below] at (2,0){$x$};
\node[below right] at (1,0){\footnotesize{1}};
\node[above left] at (0,1.5){$y$};
\node[below right] at (0,0){\(O\)};
\node[above] at (1,1){\footnotesize{\(y=x\)}};
\filldraw[orange] (.707,.707) circle (1pt);
\filldraw[black] (1,0) circle (1pt);
\node [right] at (.71,.71){\footnotesize{\(P\big(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\big)\)}};
\draw[thick,orange](-1,-1)--(1,1);
\draw[red] arc (0:45:1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it. You only need to tell Ti*k*Z where to start the `arc`. So, you essentially need to change `\draw arc (0:45:1);` to `\draw (0:1) arc (0:45:1);`:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[Triangle-Triangle] (-2,0)--(2,0);
    \draw[Triangle-Triangle] (0,-2)--(0,2);
    \draw[thick,blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \node[below] at (2,0){$x$};
    \node[below right] at (1,0){\footnotesize{1}};
    \node[above left] at (0,1.5){$y$};
    \node[below right] at (0,0){\(O\)};
    \node[above] at (1,1){\footnotesize{\(y=x\)}};
    \filldraw[orange] (.707,.707) circle (1pt);
    \filldraw[black] (1,0) circle (1pt);
    \node [right] at (.71,.71){\footnotesize{\(P\big(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\big)\)}};
    \draw[thick,orange](-1,-1)--(1,1);
    \draw[thick,red] (0:1) arc (0:45:1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to add an arrow tip to the `arc`, I would suggest that you add the `bending` library that will help you in nicely adjusting the arrow tip so that the underlying path won't become distorted. You may need to shift the labels a bit, if you want to additionally attach a label to the red line (or arrow).

Finally, note that there is another, probably preferable, way to define an `arc` path using options. Instead of `arc (0:45:1)` you would then write  `arc[start angle=0, end angle=45, radius=1]`. The same holds for `circle`: Here you would write `circle[radius=1pt]` instead of `circle (1pt)`.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[Triangle-Triangle] (-2,0)--(2,0);
    \draw[Triangle-Triangle] (0,-2)--(0,2);
    \draw[thick,blue] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
    \node[below] at (2,0){$x$};
    \node[below right] at (1,0){\footnotesize{1}};
    \node[above left] at (0,1.5){$y$};
    \node[below right] at (0,0){\(O\)};
    \node[above] at (1,1){\footnotesize{\(y=x\)}};
    \filldraw[orange] (.707,.707) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[black] (1,0) circle[radius=1pt];
    \node[right=5pt] at (.71,.71){\footnotesize{\(P\big(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\big)\)}};
    \draw[thick,orange](-1,-1)--(1,1);
    \draw[thick,red,-Triangle] (0:1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=45, radius=1] node[pos=.4,right] {$t = \frac{\pi}{4}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `[]` syntax for both `circle` and `arc` is preferred. That way we can use `delta angle` at all and we can specify `radius = 1` (not `1cm`!) at the encompassing scope and then write simply `circle[]` and `arc[start angle=0, end angle=45]` and the drawing will properly scale when a different *xy* coordinate system is set. (On the contrary, the `\filldraw`n dots should use `radius=1pt` to not scale with the coordinate system.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for pointing to `circle`. I added this in my answer.

Comment: thank you so much!